# How to get all possible combinations among rows of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need combination of the rows from the same table . Is it possible ?
Here is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE `ta` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)


INSERT INTO `ta` (`id`, `name`) VALUES 
(1, 'ta1'),
(2, 'ta2'),
(3, 'ta3'),
(4, 'ta4');
```

Result should be like below :

```
|    ta1 |    ta2 |
|    ta1 |    ta3 |
|    ta1 |    ta4 |
|    ta2 |    ta3 |
|    ta2 |    ta4 |
|    ta3 |    ta4 |
```

OR

```
|    ta1 |    ta2 |
|    ta1 |    ta3 |
|    ta1 |    ta4 |
|    ta2 |    ta1 |
|    ta2 |    ta3 |
|    ta2 |    ta4 |
|    ta3 |    ta1 |
|    ta3 |    ta2 |
|    ta3 |    ta4 |
|    ta4 |    ta1 |
|    ta4 |    ta2 |
|    ta4 |    ta3 |
```

Comment: Do self join
SELECT x.name, y.name FROM ta x JOIN ta y ON x.id < y.id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `CROSS JOIN` between the two instances of your table `ta` say `A & B`

```
SELECT 
 A.name,
 B.name FROM ta A CROSS JOIN ta B 
WHERE A.id <> B.id
```

---

[**See Demo**](http://rextester.com/live/UOFB89652)

**Note:**

If you consider `<a,b> and <b,a>` entries differently then the above query would suffice.

And if you want only one record for each pair where order doesn't matter (i.e. `<a,b> is equal to <b,a>)` then adopt the following instead:

```
SELECT 
 A.name,
 B.name FROM ta A CROSS JOIN ta B 
WHERE A.id < B.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a self join:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name
FROM ta t1
    JOIN ta t2 ON t1.id < t2.id
```