# How do I make a possible combination using MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'd like to make all possible combinations of "FRUIT" and calculate the SUM of "price."

```
    INSERT INTO MARKET(FRUIT, PRICE) VALUES ("APPLE", 2) ,("BANANA", 3) ,("GRAPE", 1)
```

In this case, the combinations that can be made in the "MARKET" are "APPLE", "BANANA", "GRAPE", "APPLE+BANANA", "APPLE+GRAPE", "BANANA+GRAPE", and "APPLE+BANANA+GRAPE".

So I want to select a table like the one below.

```
    "APPLE" 2
    "BANANA" 3
    "GRAPE" 1
    "APPLE+BANANA" 5
    "APPLE+GRAPE"3
    "BANANA+GRAPE" 4
    "APPLE+BANANA+GRAPE" 6
```

Is it possible to make the given table to the table above?

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x you can use a recursive CTE for this. I don't think it's easy if you're using older MySQL.

Comment: [mysql find all the possible combinations of one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509413/mysql-find-all-the-possible-combinations-of-one-column)

Comment: [How to get all possible combinations among rows of the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212606/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-among-rows-of-the-same-table)

Comment: [How to use mysql JOIN without ON condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470942/how-to-use-mysql-join-without-on-condition)

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search) before posting your question? The links in my other comments came from Googling for [mysql select all possible combinations](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+select+all+possible+combinations)

Comment: @Abra Those are all just pairs. The question wants all possible lengths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to find all combinations. For example:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select cast(fruit as char(100)) as fruit, price from market
 union all
  select concat(m.fruit, '+', n.fruit), m.price + n.price
  from n
  join market m on m.fruit > n.fruit
)
select * from n;
```

Result:

```
 fruit               price 
 ------------------- ----- 
 apple               2     
 banana              3     
 grape               1     
 banana+apple        5     
 grape+apple         3     
 grape+banana        4     
 grape+banana+apple  6
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KULAAFVl).